# How do I total values from several instances of one page

Tags: python, django

I'm a noob particularly at django. What I am trying to do is a variation on a simple problem:

Go to mysite/number. Get a number from a webpage form. Reload mysite/number and get a second value from the same form. Do that n times. And get the total for n.

In other words, what is my next line after total += number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
redirect(to[, permanent=False], *args, **kwargs)
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect

You can read the value of number and then again redirect the user to the same page.

You can use something like:

```
def someview(request):
    #Get your number
    #Add to total using total+=number
    return redirect('/your/desired/url')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store state somehow. This could be done via the django sessions framework.

Store the data in `request.session['number'] = 0` and continually add to that number which is persistant across a users browser session and beyond a single page view.

You could add a new submit button that has a specific name to determine when to show the total vs adding (or a link to a new "total" view  - it's up to you)

```
def myview(request):
    if not 'number' in request.session:
        request.session['number'] = 0

    if request.POST.get('show_total'):
        return http.HttpResponse(request.session['number'])

    # form here...
    if form.is_valid():
        request.session['number'] += form.cleaned_data['number']

    return render(...)
```